# cdoSendUsingPort gives 8004020f but cdoSendUsingPickup works

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, iis-6, smtp

I am using cdo to send email the following code fails

```
Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

With cdoConfig.Fields
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "localhost"
    .Update
End With
```

When I send an email I get the following error

```
8004020f
```

I then changed the code to the following:

```
Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

With cdoConfig.Fields
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPickup
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "localhost"
    .Update
End With
```

The email sends without a problem. What steps could I take to troubleshoot why cdoSendUsingPort is not working?

Answer (score 2):

With `cdoSendUsingPort`, CDO tries to open a connection to the [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) server you specify (in your case, `localhost`) on TCP port 25. I guess you're not running an `SMTP` server on your machine, so nothing is listening on port 25 and the call fails.

With `cdoSendUsingPickup`, CDO forwards the message to the [pickup directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526208%28EXCHG.10%29.aspx) of your local IIS instance for later processing. I guess you have IIS installed on your machine and its SMTP module is configured to use pickup, so the call succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Professor [Google](http://tinyurl.com/3yq2p8o) finds (in order):
 - [Several options](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/why-does-cdo-message-give-me-8004020f-errors.html):  server disallows anonymous relaying, server rejects specific recipient domains, recipient is rejected by SMTP server in unexpected way, and/or proxy or firewall settings are blocking the mail.
 - [Your mailserver is configured to not relay from your source machine.](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/53504-cdo-error-8004020f)
 - ... and several more things which boil down to the first link listed.

Some of these things you can test directly by telnet-ing from the sending machine to the mailserver, [performing a normal SMTP interaction](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html), and seeing what messages are displayed.